# Refresh page when container div is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple and pretty straightforward question:
If media query breakpoints are set at 750px and 970px, using jquery, is it possible to refresh the page after the width of .container div changes on browser resize and how?

Comment: ew, why are you doing this? this is not the correct way to fix CSS problems...

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: It's complicated. Basically, I need to manipulate the DOM on media query breakpoints, so I need to refresh the page when breakpoints are triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a media query instead but, you can listen to a resize event if you really want to do this:

```
addEventListener('resize', function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

If you want to only reload if a breakpoint is past, you can keep track of the last innerWidth and only reload if a certain value is crossed. Or instead of using innerWidth, use a width of a div. For example:

```
var last = document.getElementById('mydiv').clientWidth;
addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var current = document.getElementById('mydiv').clientWidth;
    if (current != last) location.reload();
    last = current;
});
```

Comment: No no, I really need to refresh the page because I'm manipulating the DOM on media query breakpoints, and the results aren't visible until the page is refreshed. I already tried the resize event but it refreshes every time the browser is resizedd and I need to trigger resize only after width  of the .container div changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <h1>Page Resize demo</h1>
</div>
<script>
    $(window).resize(function () 
    {
        if ($(window).width() < 700) 
        {
            $("#mydiv").css("background", "red");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $("#mydiv").css("background", "orange");
        }
    });
</script>
```